# Weighted city-block distance algorithm with diagonal movement

Tags: distance, path-finding, diagonal

What is the correct algorithm for measuring distance between two nodes in a grid that allows diagonal movement?

I've thought of using Euclidean distance but was told that it was wrong. I searched for solutions and this code came up, but I am not sure if it is correct:

```
D * (dx + dy) + (D2 - 2 * D) * min(dx, dy)
```

where D2 is the cost of diagonal movement. If this equation is correct, how can I incorporate weight into it?

Comment: will all the same movements have the same weight? by that I mean will every diagonal movement have the same weight as every other diagonal movement? and are X and Y movements of the same weight as each other?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a graph you probably will want one. Once you have a graph set up so that each node knows which other nodes it's connected to and the weight of moving to those nodes (make an edge class for this) you should be able to use Dijkstra's algorithm or the A* algorithm to find the shortest path. 
now that you have the shortest path it is no trouble to calculate the weight/distance accosted with the path.

If you are not clear on what a graph (interconnected nodes) let me know and I'll explain further.

There are lots of tutorials for making graphs and weighted graphs online. like wise for Dijkstra's algorithm (which I find easier to understand then A* but usually runs a little slower)